# Обособление слова «плюс»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, значение-слов

Нужно ли ставить запятую после слова "плюс" в этом предложении?

> Китай продолжает вводить локдауны из-за COVID-19, провоцируя ипотечный
> кризис; плюс с апреля 2022 идёт не связанный с этим банковский
> кризис.

Answer (score 2):

Вот что имеется в словаре Ефремовой:
[плюс](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Efremova-term-72290.htm)
**3.** **Наречие**. Прибавляя, добавляя что-либо.

В этом предложении теоретически вместо точки с запятой можно поставить точку. Можно, кстати, и дальше развивать *плюсовые* рассуждения:
*Китай продолжает вводить локдауны из-за COVID-19, провоцируя ипотечный кризис. Плюс с апреля 2022 идёт не связанный с этим банковский кризис. Плюс с мая...*

Слово "плюс", имеющее в этом контексте значение *в добавление, в дополнение, вдобавок*, не обособляется.

С одной стороны, понятно, что родители хотят увидеться с друзьями и не могут оставить ребенка, с другой ― вечером люди все-таки выпивают, все громче, чем днем, **плюс** с детьми сложно задержаться в баре надолго. [Место ли детям в барах? Отвечают рестораторы (03.2018) // Афиша Daily, 2018]

Comment: Наречие может являться союзом? Можете прокомментировать http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=1460  А также высказать мнение об этом ресурсе, в том числе о его сомнительном названии.  Также интересно: при наличии "плюс" мы имеем сочинительную или бессоюзную связь?

Comment: Здесь указан источник: https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/493/плюс

Comment: Они пишут: по материалам сайта Грамота.ру, где эти материалы? А у Академика откуда сведения, у них  есть ссылки на официальные правила, на грамматику, можно им доверять? Я смотрю, у них много разных тем, такие вот крутые специалисты. К РАН имеют отношение?  В грамматике это точно не СПП. У них такие правила: Я его пригласил, ПОЧЕМУ он и пришел (СПП). Я его пригласил, И поэтому он пришел (ССП).  Я его пригласил, поэтому он и пришел (БСП).

Comment: Наречие - это союзный аналог, а не союз,  а союз он только в школьной практике. Поэтому мне интересно мнение Грамоты.ру, они хотя бы с РАН связаны.

Comment: Это не совсем по материалам, это и есть материалы. Насколько помню, они издавались, иначе бы не был бы указан год. *где эти материалы?* — хороший вопрос, на Грамоте ссылки меняют и статьи удаляют (наверно, из соображений о нужности). *Два плюс два* — здесь точно союз, у них похожий пример. На Академике информация из словарей и т.п. (поэтому им можно доверять), вот весь список: https://academic.ru, ничего своего у них нет, к РАН отношения нет, если есть, то это указывают.

Comment: Слова, слова, мне же нужно точное обоснование, обозначенное в источниках. А пока у меня единственный источник –  толковые словари, где написано, что это наречие.  Там нет даже такой записи – используется в значении союза. Я еще понимаю, что наречие можно применять в качестве присоединительных союзов для обособленных членов, но в сложном предложении они даже на это не тянут.  И уж тем более не могут быть сочинительными союзами в сложном предложении.

Comment: Почитайте словарь: 2. неизм. Разг. Указывает на то, что второе прибавляется к первому. Четыре п. два будет шесть. 3. неизм. Прибавляя, дополняя что-л. уже известное; с прибавлением чего-л. Оплата железнодорожных билетов п. командировочные.  И это все – разговорные конструкции. Так что одна "отсебятина" в ваших так называемых учебных материалах, которые выдают себя за академические.

Comment: Сравните: *два и два — четыре; два плюс два — четыре*. В БТС часть речи не указана. В словаре Ожегова и Шведовой (ведущий автор вашей любимой грамматики) сказано про союз, и не единожды.

Answer (score 1):

‟Плюс” в этом предложении это присоединительный союз, как ‟к тому же”, поэтому перед ним ставится запятая. После ‟плюс” не ставится запятая, так как она не ставится после присоединительных союзов.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на источник (почему присоединительный союз). Кстати, там точка с запятой стоит.  И это какой вид сложного предложения?

Comment: http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=1460

Comment: Если союз присоединительный, то это, внезапно, предложение с сложносочинённой связью.

Comment: Приложение сложное, там при любом союзе будет стоять запятая, а также в БСП без союза. А точку с запятой можно поставить?  Интересно, почему в толковом словаре не указано значение присоединительного союза?

Comment: Например, если есть союз ‟но”, то точку с запятой ставят, когда пауза больше, чем стандартная при такой связи, — а тут почему? Возможно, можно поставить по такой же причине, но смысл её обозначать в какой-то такой новостной статье?  Нет, я не вижу причин ставить точку с запятой.

Comment: Там написано, что это сочинительный союз, но в ЗНАЧЕНИИ ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНОГО ставится запятая. Если сочинительный ‟и” в значении присоединительного, то это присоединительный союз, а если ‟плюс”, то написали, что ‟в значении присоединительного”. Обычное долбоящерство составителей словарей.

Comment: Это не в словаре написано, а в каких-то учебных материалах.  Здесь еще больше оснований поставить точку с запятой. В первом предложении есть свои знаки.  Разная тематика сообщений.

Comment: Мало ли что и где написано, здесь нет причин для точки с запятой. Это обычное присоединение, причём здесь вообще тематика.

Comment: Это причины для постановки точки с запятой.

Comment: Это не БСП, а ССП. В ССП не важна тематика

Comment: Ладно, закончили. Это именно БСП, а "плюс" там на правах обычного наречия "вдобавок" Ссылку даете на неофициальные правила.

Comment: Считайте как хотите. Мне очевидно, что это типичное долбоящерство составителей словарей и присоединительный союз.

Comment: Мне просто хотелось увидеть  официальные сведения по слову "плюс", у вас их нет.

Comment: Там написано следующее: ‟Если союз 'плюс' употребляется в присоединительном значении (то же, что 'вдобавок', 'к тому же'), то перед ним ставится запятая”. Даже если не считать это присоединительным союзом, то по этим записям это сочинительный с присоединительным значением, перед которым ставится запятая.

Comment: Точка с запятой уже стоит. Это неправильно?  И почему я должна доверять неизвестному сайту. Откуда там материалы? Пусть тоже ссылки дают.